# Why is ConnectedThresholdImageFilter class not labeling pixels within threshold?

Tags: python, itk, simpleitk

I am trying to use the ConnectedThresholdImageFilter class to segment the "C" looking white region of a binary image ('slice87.jpg'). The idea was to pick a seed value that was lies within the region and only add neighboring pixels that also have an intensity of 255 (between threshold of 254 and 256).

[image: "slice87.jpg"]

However, my code results in an image with every pixel set to 0:

[image]

Instead of this (manually edited through photoshop):

[image]

My seed value was (x,y) = (115,35). `img.GetPixel(115,35)` returns 255.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.ReadImage('slice87.jpg')
seeds = [(115,35)]

output = sitk.ConnectedThreshold(image1=img,
                                 seedList = seeds,
                                 lower = 254,
                                 upper = 256,
                                 replaceValue = 255)
sitk.WriteImage(output, 'output.jpg')
```

Comment: Are you using the image from this post, or a different one? If latter, the intensities might not be quite correct due to loss from JPEG compression.

Comment: The actual image is a 3D binary image saved in the hdr/img analyze format. I saved slice87 as a jpg so that I could upload it to stackoverflow. The intensity for white regions range from 251-255, so the compression does not explain why all the pixels are set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the type of your input image `img`? I suspect it is of type `sitkUInt8`, in which case the value 256 is not able to be represented as the input image's pixel type and is siently causing integer overflow. The lower and upper parameters form a closed interval which include the specified bounds. You should specify the `upper` parameter as 255 or `Cast` your image to another pixel type.